# How do I set the title and description of my Quarto website for the metadata that pops up on LinkedIn, iMessage, etc.?

Tags: html, css, facebook-opengraph, quarto

I've created a personal website to display some of my portfolio and writing using Quarto. I would like to send this website to recruiters on LinkedIn and to my friends, but when I do, the website preview has an incorrect title. It pulls one of the headers from the landing page, instead of the title that I have specified in the `_quarto.yml` file. The website is [davidenders.me](https://davidenders.me/) if you'd like to see for yourself. I want the preview card to just say "David Enders". Instead, it looks like this ("All-Hands Meeting Recap Generator" is a header from the middle of the page): [image: The current view of the preview card]

I've followed the steps in the [docs](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/projects/websites.html#twitter-card) to add Twitter Card and Open Graph metadata to the configuration file, but it hasn't seemed to work. Here is my configuration file, `_quarto.yml`:

```
project:
  type: website
  title: "David Enders"
  output-dir: docs

website:
  title: "David Enders"
  favicon: media/favicon.ico
  twitter-card:
    title: "David Enders"
    description: "David Enders' personal website. Projects, resume, and blog posts."
    image: media/headshot.jpg
  open-graph:
    title: "David Enders"
    description: "David Enders' personal website. Projects, resume, and blog posts."
    image: media/headshot.jpg

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
    toc: true
```

Comment: Can you check again. I use https://open-graph-preview.com/ to check if there is a problem with `https://davidenders.me/` but I can visualize "David Enders". Can you provide a provisional link where this happens?

Comment: In my case, where maybe is different in other locations, the only problem I detect is with the image related to `headshot.jpg` but not the title.